# variable may be used before being set

Tags: c, memory-management, initialization, malloc

I am getting "variable may be used before being set" when I create a pointer to a structure `example *e`. If I use a variable instead `example e`, I am not getting the error. Is this because I haven't allocated memory for the pointer?

```
typedef struct example {
    int a;
}example;

void test (){

    example *e;
    e->a=1;
    printf_all("val %d",e->a);
}
```

Comment: How can you use a non-pointer variable instead and have this code compiled??? (BTW, you couldn't even bother to write the title properly?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`e` is NOT pointing to anything. You are using an uninitialized pointer. You "set" through an invalid pointer, and then trying to access it.

Your pointer should point to an `example` instance. For example:

```
example exampleInstance;
example * examplePointer = &exampleInstance;
```

Answer (score 5):

The pointer has an indeterminate value. As result the program has undefined behaviour.

You should allocate memory for an object of type `example` where you are going to write data. For example

```
example *e = malloc( sizeof( *e ) );
e->a = 1;
```

In this case you should free the memory when it will not be needed any more.

Or

```
example obj;
example *e = &obj;
e->a = 1;
```